# Seeking App Recommendations for Advanced Camera Controls on iPhone 15 Pro Max

Tags: gratis, iphone-app, camera, iso

Can the iPhone 15 Pro Max adjust ISO, aperture, and shutter speed? It seems the built-in camera lacks direct controls for shutter speed and aperture, though I've noticed some third-party apps can manage these settings. However, many of these apps require a purchase or only offer a short free trial.

Could you recommend a free camera app, as well as an affordable paid option, that allows for professional-level camera control?